# Regular expression to select substrings

Tags: python, regex, awk, sed

I am trying to write regular expression which will select some of the part of string and ignore rest part

I have an below text and want regular expression to extract the string """ Text to be selected """ (ignore white spaces) from all lines and ignore rest string

```
"""Text to be selected"""
""" Text to be selected """
""" Text to be selected Text not to be selected"""
Text not to be selected """ Text to be selected Text not to be selected"""
```

I tried following regular expression

```
[\s]?"""[\s]|[\S]Text to be selected[\s]|[\S].*"""
```

But it selecting all the string as at the end it has ".*".

It returning string

```
"""Text to be selected"""
""" Text to be selected """
""" Text to be selected Text not to be selected"""
Text not to be selected """ Text to be selected Text not to be selected"""
```

but i need string

```
"""Text to be selected"""
""" Text to be selected """
""" Text to be selected """
""" Text to be selected """
```

Comment: @Tiw I am trying to use this code in sed command and tried command sed -i "s/[\s]?\"\"\"[\\s]|[\\S]Text to be selected[\\s]|[\\S].*\"\"\"//g" file1.txt. Want to try this regex in python if possible

Comment: You don't need reply this in comment, add them into your question instead.

Comment: @vsmahajan, by seeing your profile came to know you never select an answer as correct one. Please give sometime to your post and when you have enough answers on board then try to select anyone of them as correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -E 's/[^"]*(""" ?Text to be selected ?)[^"]*(""").*/\1\2/' file
```

**Explanations:**

- `[^"]*`: search for non quote characters
- `(""" ?Text to be selected ?)`: capture `"""` followed by optional space and matching text
- `[^"]*`: search for zero or more non quote characters
- `(""")`: captures ending `"""`
- `\1\2`: output captured text and ending `"""`

Comment: @vsmahajan, very good that you have selected an answer as correct one, try to select correct answers from your previous questions too. Also you could encourage users which are giving helpful answers by up-voting too, happy learning on this greatb site.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/^\"\"\".*\"\"\"$/{
  if(match($0,/Text to be selected/)){
    print substr($0,1,3),substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),substr($0,length($0)-2)
  }
}'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your specific cases and this works:

```
def matchme(string):
    match = (re.match('.*("""\s*Text to be selected\s*).*(""").*',string))
    if (match is not None):
        return match[1]+match[2]
    else:
        return ''
```

The idea is to 'catch' the matches, skip the rest, and then reconstruct the string. Hope this is general enough for you

Answer (score 0):

Try Perl

```
$ cat mahajan.txt
"""Text to be selected"""
""" Text to be selected """
""" Text to be selected Text not to be selected"""
Text not to be selected """ Text to be selected Text not to be selected"""

$  perl -lne ' /("""\s*Text to be selected)(.+?)?(""")/ and print "$1$3" ' mahajan.txt
"""Text to be selected"""
""" Text to be selected"""
""" Text to be selected"""
""" Text to be selected"""

$
```